# How can I create a subset data frame according to a factor's levels?

Tags: r, dataframe, split, subset

I've got this dataframe:

```
> temp_table
       word word_count    sentiment
1      love      28577          joy
2      love      28577     positive
3      time      12900 anticipation
4      baby       5748          joy
5      baby       5748     positive
6      shit       5384        anger
7      shit       5384      disgust
8      shit       5384     negative
9      good       5216 anticipation
10     good       5216          joy
```

and I want to create a dataframe for each different level of "sentiment". So i used the function split:

```
subset_list <- split(temp_table, temp_table$sentiment)
```

that returned a list of the different dataframes:

```
> subset_list
$joy
       word word_count    sentiment
1      love      28577          joy
4      baby       5748          joy
10     good       5216          joy

$anticipation
       word word_count    sentiment
3      time      12900 anticipation
9      good       5216 anticipation

$positive
       word word_count    sentiment
2      love      28577     positive
5      baby       5748     positive

...
```

How can I separate each dataframe, giving as name the name of the correspondent sentiment?

I would like to have the dataframes "joy", "anticipation" and so on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need `list2env`

```
list2env(split(temp_table, temp_table$sentiment), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `assign` on a `for` loop

```
for(nm in unique(temp_table$sentiment)) {
    assign(nm, subset(temp_table, sentiment == nm))
}
```